# How do I choose default python homebrew version?

Tags: python, homebrew, python-3.11, python-3.12

I have all three versions of python 3.10, 3.11 and 3.12 using homebrew. but somehow homebrew defaults to using 3.11 as the default.

when i type `which python3`, it shows 3.11.6 as the version instead of 3.12. why did it default to 3.11 and how do i change this to 3.12?

I was expecting the latest version 3.12 to be the default.

Comment: How did you install them and in which order? Where are they installed and what's in your `PATH`? Perhaps look at e.g. `pyenv` if you need to switch between versions.

Comment: If you don't need the earlier versions then probably worth using brew to delete them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that Homebrew defaults to Python 3.11.6 due to the current configuration of your system PATH or the way Homebrew has linked the Python versions. To change the default version to Python 3.12, you might want to try the following steps:

1. Check Homebrew Linking: 
   Check the linking status of Python 3.12 using Homebrew:

```bash
brew info python@3.12
```

2. Alter the System PATH (if necessary): 
   If Python 3.12 is correctly linked but not coming first in the PATH, you may need to alter the system PATH. Update your shell profile (e.g., `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile`) to put the directory containing Python 3.12 executable before others:

```py
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.12/bin:$PATH"
```

3. Utilize Homebrew Linking (with caution): 
   Alternatively, you might try using Homebrew's `link` command to change the default Python version. Be cautious as this could lead to broken dependencies:

```bash
brew link --overwrite python@3.12
```

4. Consider Using `pyenv`: 
   For a more robust solution, consider using pyenv to manage multiple Python versions:

```bash
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.12.0
pyenv global 3.12.0
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue seems to be in the difference between [python@3.11](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/b87c13c9f4c2d97bc4302fdbfb0f52cb0682ade3/Formula/p/python%403.11.rb#L57) and [python@3.12](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/b87c13c9f4c2d97bc4302fdbfb0f52cb0682ade3/Formula/p/python%403.12.rb#L314) Homebrew Ruby scripts.

[3.11](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/b87c13c9f4c2d97bc4302fdbfb0f52cb0682ade3/Formula/p/python%403.11.rb#L57) has `link_overwrite` for python3 which sets a bunch of symlinks in `/usr/local/bin/` (which is usually in your `$PATH`) to use [3.11](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/b87c13c9f4c2d97bc4302fdbfb0f52cb0682ade3/Formula/p/python%403.11.rb#L57).

[3.12](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/b87c13c9f4c2d97bc4302fdbfb0f52cb0682ade3/Formula/p/python%403.12.rb#L314) lacks this and so your shell is not seeing them.

You can rectify this either by modifying your `$PATH` as in the other reply, or replacing the symlink manually:

```
cd /usr/local/bin && rm python3 && ln -s ../Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.1/bin/python3.12 python3
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit 2024-02-25:** About four days ago, the below PR was merged.  I believe `brew install python` should now install Python 3.12.

---

`python3` in Homebrew won't point at 3.12 until [this PR is merged](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/150390).  AFAIK Homebrew don't switch the default `python3` to the latest version until all the Python software that Homebrew packages are confirmed to work with the new version.

If you really need `python3` to point at 3.12 globally right now, I personally like [@Iskander14yo's suggestion to use pyenv (above)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77332539).